# Cannot autowire bean that overrides a method that is overriden in parent

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inheritance

In our project we have a structure similiar to code below. If I uncomment the specified block Spring will fail to autowire PrintService in the PrintController

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'PrintController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private printService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [MyPrintService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Why is Spring having issues with it?

```
@Controller
public class PrintController {
   @Autowired
   private MyPrintService printService;
}

@Service
public class MyPrintService extends AbstractPrintService<MyModel> {
   /* uncomment this block to get error
   @Override
   public void print(MyModel model){
       //do stuff 
   }*/
}


public abstract class AbstractPrintService<M> extends CommonAbstractPrintService<M> {
}


public abstract class CommonAbstractPrintService<M> implements PrintService<M> {
   @Override
   public void print(M model){
       //do common stuff 
   }
}

public interface PrintService<M> {
   void print(M model);
}
```

The solution was to autowire the bean using interface. So instead of:

```
 @Autowired
 private MyPrintService printService;
```

I used

```
@Autowired
private PrintService printService;
```

And it suddenly worked. But I have no Idea why Spring was offended by that override. Would be glad if anyone could explain that! Thanks!

Comment: where `PrintService` comes from? You implemented it or is some library class? Also, please post the error :)

Comment: All classes and interface are part of the example. There are no libraries other than Spring used.